# RAM timing/frequency issues, impossible to enable XMP profile

Tags: memory, cpu, bios, ddr, xmp

## The problem

My RAM is supposed to run in XMP 2.0 at 1600MHz with the following timings

- CAS Latency: 16
- RAS to CAS: 18
- RAS precharge: 18
- tRAS: 38
- TRC: 56

As you can see there that's the expected settings:

[image: XMP profile]

Instead it runs with those timings:

[image: Wrong timings]

The problem is then: how to make my RAM run on correct/XMP2.0 timings?

## What I have tried

I have tried to go to the BIOS -> enable the XMP 2.0 profile, therefore selecting the "3200" settings (corresponding in reality to 1600MHz).

I saved the modification in the BIOS -> the computer rebooted...4 times in a row -> then started "normally" and had reset the changes that I did in the BIOS -> resulting in the settings you can see above (1066 MHz - 15 15 15 36 51 2T)

I also tried to use the "Gigabyte App Center" and modify those settings from Windows (10 x64 Professional) -> after a reboot and several "self-reboot" -> same results as with direct modifications in the BIOS

## Hardware setup

### RAM

4x16GB G.Skill F4-3200C16D-32GIS

The four RAM modules are the same model:
https://www.gskill.com/product/165/185/1567584227/F4-3200C16D-32GIS

I bought them at two different times:

- First pair is from: https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B07YV6DKJK/ref=ppx_od_dt_b_asin_title_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1
- Second pair is from: https://www.alternate.fr/html/product/1584069

### CPU

AMD Ryzen 9 5900x

[image: CPU AMD Ryzen 9 5900x]

### Motherboard

Gigabyte x570 UD rev 1.0

https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/X570-UD-rev-10/sp#sp

[image: Motherboard Gigabyte X570 UD]

## Additional info/questions

### Slot numbering in CPU-Z and correspondence on the motherboard

In CPU-Z the Slots are numbered from 1 to 4
However, physically, the slot numbered 1 in CPU-Z and the slot numbered 2 in CPU-Z are NOT next to each other.

On the motherboard the slots are actually (from left to right, or if you prefer, from closest to the CPU to furthest to the CPU), if I use the CPU-Z numbering then the physical layout is like so:
1-3-2-4

### Four screenshots of the four different memory modules (CPU-Z)

This is for reference and for supporting the following section containing some questions.

#### Slot 1

[image: RAM Slot 1]

#### Slot 2

[image: RAM Slot 2]

#### Slot 3

[image: RAM Slot 3]

#### Slot 4

[image: Slot 4]

### Questions

#### Question 1

As you can see on the above screenshots the manufacturers are different. Memory modules on slots 1 and 2 are built by SK Hynix and memory modules on slots 3 and 4 are built by Nanya technology

Do you think that the manufacturers being different could be of any issue here?

#### Question 2

On the CPU-Z screenshots for each memory module you can see that there's a category called "ranks". I have tried to look it up and understand if it's of any importance...but did not get conclusive information.

Is this "ranks" thing of any importance?
Can it be the source of the "incompatibility" leading to poor timings/frequency in my hardware setup?

## EDIT

By manually setting the RAM frequency to 1500 (DDR4-3000) and setting manually the timings to what they should be 16-18-18-38-56 and 1T (for the command rate) -> the system boots.

Oh and I also manually set the voltage to 1,350V as it is the recommended settings for XMP.

So I am actually exactly on optimized settings yet, but I am getting close.

There's still this mystery about the "ranks" thing and of course the remaining 200MHz (I am gonna try successive approximations to try and get there)

Comment: I've seen some systems that can only enable higher memory profiles when two slots are fitted rather than four. Can you take out the sticks in slots A1 & B1, leaving sticks in A2 & B2 and retry?

Comment: Thanks @Mokubai for your help! In the end what I did is: update the bios. And set everything manually. I ended up getting a stable result at 1500MHz (DDR4-3000) with the following timings 16-18-18-38-56-1T and I manually set the voltage at 1.350V. The computer boots with no issue, and so far everything is stable.

Comment: Fair enough, glad you found a solution. You can post an answer with your solution and you should be able to accept it in a couple of days. https://superuser.com/help/self-answer

Comment: The fact that the DRAM manufacturer is different probably confuses the issue - plus, the majority of AMD (AM4 at least) boards are rubbish at supporting anything more than 2 slots populated, at least running any XMP profiles - and since those "Nanya" DRAMS run  maximum non-XMP at 1066, that's what you end up with. At least, that's my guess

Comment: @Bravo do you have sources for what you say about the Nanya DRAMS running maximum at 1066

Comment: I said their maximum non-XMP speed is 1066 according to the screenshots **YOU** posted - I was also referring to the chips in the RAM sticks **you** have, not the Nanya brand *in general*

Answer (score 0):

I removed my previous answer.

The solution was actually: RTFM

And by RTFM I mean, read the Qualified Vendor List (QVL) for my motherboard (Gigabyte x570 UD).

For reference it's there:
https://download.gigabyte.com/FileList/Memory/mb_memory_x570-ud_renoir_200918.pdf

Yes, it was kind of obvious, but for some reasons I did not think about it.

So, if you click on the link above you can actually see that the list of compatible RAM is long, sure, but if you try to select RAM randomly without taking into account the QVL the probability of selecting an incompatible set is actually very high.

So? -> RTFM :')